# Logstash Grok pattern to cut split a string in the log line using regex

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

Below is the field that is part of a log line from the application, where have client-id attributes value that I need to split, delimitter '#'.

```
client-id=ABC-SYNC_Foo#qrkmguv4p995b3kqk1jaupocl2
```

here is how i want

```
source=ABC-SYNC_Foo
id=qrkmguv4p995b3kqk1jaupocl2
```

I need help with regex on how to split it in within a single line.

Comment: Maybe [`client-id=(?<source>[^#]*)#(?<id>.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/sO5pI3/1)?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using

```
client-id=(?<source>[^#]*)#(?<id>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sO5pI3/1)

The pattern matches:

- `client-id=` -  a literal character sequence `client-id=`
- `(?<source>[^#]*)` - Group "source" matching zero or more characters other than `#` up to the first...
- `#` - literal hash symbol followed with...
- `(?<id>.*)` - any 0 or more characters other than a newline (Group "id")

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for the suggestion, following Regex worked for me:

```
client-id=(?<source>[^#]*)#(?<id>.*)
```